# How to make an accordion menu with saving in cookies the position(code included)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, nodes

PHP:

```
function renderCategories($parent, $categories, $expand_by_button, $expand_by_text){
    if (count($categories) > 0){
        if (is_expanded($parent)){
            echo '<ul class="main_menu" ' . ($parent ? 'style="padding-left:12px;"' : '') . 'id="category_'.$parent['id'].'">';
        } else {
            echo '<ul style="display:none;' . ($parent ? 'padding-left:12px;"' : '') . '" id="category_'.$parent['id'].'">';
        }
        foreach ($categories as $category){

            if ((count($category['children']) > 0) && ($expand_by_button)){
                echo '<li>';
                if (is_expanded($category)){
                    echo '<img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-collapse.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-'.$category['id'].'">';
                } else {
                    echo '<img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-'.$category['id'].'">';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<li style="padding-left:12px">';
            }

            if ($category['is_current']) 
            {
                if($category['thumble'])
                {
                    $image = '<img src="image/'.$category['thumble'].'" />';
                }
                else
                {
                    $image = '';
                }
                echo $image.'<b current="1" class="category_button" id="image-'.$category['id'].'" style="cursor: pointer;">';
            }

            if (count($category['children']) > 0){
                if ($expand_by_text){
                    echo '<a class="category_id" style="cursor:pointer;margin-top:-14px; padding-left:12px; display: inline-block" href="#" title="'.$category['alt'].'" alt="'.$category['alt'].'" id="button-'.$category['id'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a>';
                } else if ($expand_by_button){
                    if ($category['is_current']){
                        echo $category['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo '<a class="category_button" id="button-'.$category['id'].'" href="'.$category['href'].'" title="'.$category['alt'].'" alt="'.$category['alt'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<a class="category_id category_button" style="cursor:pointer" href="#" title="'.$category['alt'].'" alt="'.$category['alt'].'" id="button-'.$category['id'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a>';
                }
            } else {
                if ($category['is_current']){
                    echo $category['name'];
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="'.$category['href'].'" title="'.$category['alt'].'" alt="'.$category['alt'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a>';
                }
            }

            if ($category['is_current']) echo '</b>';

            renderCategories($category, $category['children'], $expand_by_button, $expand_by_text);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div id="shoputils_category" class="middle"><?php renderCategories(null, $categories, $expand_by_button == 1, $expand_by_text == 1) ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
    if(!Array.indexOf){
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
            for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
                if(this[i]==obj){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
    function categoryAdd(id) {
        var ids = new String($.cookie('expanded')).split(',');
        if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1){
            ids.push(id);
            $.cookie('expanded', ids.join(','), {path: '/'});
        }
    }
    function categoryRemove(id) {
        var ids = new String($.cookie('expanded')).split(',');

        // bug #7654 fixed
        while (ids.indexOf(id) != -1) {
            ids.splice(ids.indexOf(id), 1);
        }
         $.cookie('expanded', ids.join(','), {path: '/'});
    }




    $('.category_button').click(function(e){



        var change = '<?= $change; ?>';
        var current = $(this).attr('current');

        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];


        toggleMenu(e,id)

    });

function toggleMenu(e, id)
{

            var button = $('#image-'+ id);
            if ($('#category_'+id).css('display') == 'none'){
                button.attr('src', 'catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-collapse.png');
                categoryAdd(id);
            } else {
                button.attr('src', 'catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png');
                categoryRemove(id);
            }
                $('#category_'+id).toggle(200);

}
```

description:

By now I have a menu, and when I click on some category in the menu, that category opens and then that is saved to cookies , if the user refreshes the page, the menu will save the same position as before, so as you see in the javascript: - I have a variable `$change` this variable indicates if the menu categories can be opened all at one time OR one category menu can be opened at one time or its called "accordion", how to implement to this code the posibility to hide all the other categories when I click on some category to open and then that is saved to cookies, so this is the generated html:

as you see every `<ul>` tag is a category that have an id, the question is: how can i hide all other categories when opening one and then save it into cookies, like in the code above..

```
<ul class="main_menu" style="padding-left:12px;" id="category_256"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/navolochki/" title="Наволочки" alt="Наволочки">Наволочки <sup>5</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pledy/" title="Пледы" alt="Пледы">Пледы <sup>3</sup></a></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-257"><b current="1" class="category_button" id="image-257" style="cursor: pointer;">Полотенца <sup>19</sup></b><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_257"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/polotence/polotence_bannoe/" title="Банные полотенца" alt="Банные полотенца">Банные полотенца <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/polotence/kuhonnie_polotenca/" title="Кухонные полотенца" alt="Кухонные полотенца">Кухонные полотенца <sup>19</sup></a></li></ul></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-59"><a class="category_button" id="button-59" href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/" title="Покрывала" alt="Покрывала">Покрывала <sup>26</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_59"><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-99"><a class="category_button" id="button-99" href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/" title="по цвету" alt="по цвету">по цвету <sup>15</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_99"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_begh/" title="беж" alt="беж">беж <sup>3</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_belyj/" title="белый" alt="белый">белый <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_blu/" title="блю" alt="блю">блю <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokrivalo_color_bordovyj/" title="бордовый" alt="бордовый">бордовый <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_braun/" title="браун" alt="браун">браун <sup>5</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_vinograd/" title="виноград" alt="виноград">виноград <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_grafit/" title="графит" alt="графит">графит <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_grin/" title="грин" alt="грин">грин <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_ghins/" title="джинс" alt="джинс">джинс <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_kakao/" title="какао" alt="какао">какао <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_kirpich/" title="кирпич" alt="кирпич">кирпич <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_kremovii/" title="крем" alt="крем">крем <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_lavanda/" title="лаванда" alt="лаванда">лаванда <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_lajt/" title="лайт" alt="лайт">лайт <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_malahit/" title="малахит" alt="малахит">малахит <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_med/" title="мёд" alt="мёд">мёд <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_mix/" title="микс" alt="микс">микс <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_pion/" title="пион" alt="пион">пион <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_roza/" title="роза" alt="роза">роза <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_red/" title="рэд" alt="рэд">рэд <sup>6</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_serebro/" title="серебро" alt="серебро">серебро <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_terra/" title="терра" alt="терра">терра <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_fresh/" title="фреш" alt="фреш">фреш <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_cvetu/pokryvalo_color_chokolad/" title="шоколад" alt="шоколад">шоколад <sup>4</sup></a></li></ul></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-88"><a class="category_button" id="button-88" href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/" title="по названию" alt="по названию">по названию <sup>26</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_88"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/argentina/" title="Аргентина" alt="Аргентина">Аргентина <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/viola/" title="Виола" alt="Виола">Виола <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/zelenyj_chaj/" title="Зелёный чай" alt="Зелёный чай">Зелёный чай <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/irlandia/" title="Ирландия" alt="Ирландия">Ирландия <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/kantri/" title="Кантри" alt="Кантри">Кантри <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/kokos/" title="Кокос" alt="Кокос">Кокос <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/lajt/" title="Лайт" alt="Лайт">Лайт <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/marsel/" title="Марсель" alt="Марсель">Марсель <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/mexsika/" title="Мексика" alt="Мексика">Мексика <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/pion/" title="Пион" alt="Пион">Пион <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/radughnoe/" title="Радужное" alt="Радужное">Радужное <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/rivera/" title="Ривьера" alt="Ривьера">Ривьера <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/russkij_folk/" title="Русский Фолк" alt="Русский Фолк">Русский Фолк <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/smart/" title="Смарт" alt="Смарт">Смарт <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/tradicija/" title="Традиция" alt="Традиция">Традиция <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/flauers/" title="Флауэрс" alt="Флауэрс">Флауэрс <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/fughen/" title="Фьюжен" alt="Фьюжен">Фьюжен <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_nazvaniu/jamajka/" title="Ямайка" alt="Ямайка">Ямайка <sup>1</sup></a></li></ul></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-86"><a class="category_button" id="button-86" href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/" title="по размеру" alt="по размеру">по размеру <sup>26</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_86"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/150x200/" title="150x200" alt="150x200">150x200 <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/160%D1%85220/" title="160х220" alt="160х220">160х220 <sup>14</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/200x220/" title="200x220" alt="200x220">200x220 <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/200x240/" title="200x240" alt="200x240">200x240 <sup>9</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/220%D1%85240/" title="220х240" alt="220х240">220х240 <sup>1</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_razmeru/240%D1%85240/" title="240х240" alt="240х240">240х240 <sup>1</sup></a></li></ul></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-124"><a class="category_button" id="button-124" href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_risunku/" title="по рисунку" alt="по рисунку">по рисунку <sup>26</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_124"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_risunku/pokryvala_v_kletku/" title="в клетку" alt="в клетку">в клетку <sup>3</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_risunku/pokryvala_v_polosku/" title="в полоску" alt="в полоску">в полоску <sup>10</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_risunku/pokryvala_odnotonnye/" title="однотонные" alt="однотонные">однотонные <sup>13</sup></a></li></ul></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-87"><a class="category_button" id="button-87" href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_plotnosti/" title="по плотности" alt="по плотности">по плотности <sup>26</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_87"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_plotnosti/270_gr_m/" title="270 гр/м" alt="270 гр/м">270 гр/м <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_plotnosti/340_gr_m/" title="340 гр/м" alt="340 гр/м">340 гр/м <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_plotnosti/350_gr_m/" title="350 гр/м" alt="350 гр/м">350 гр/м <sup>2</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/pokrivala/pokryvala_po_plotnosti/370_gr_m/" title="370 гр/м" alt="370 гр/м">370 гр/м <sup>20</sup></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-collapse.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-128"><a class="category_button" id="button-128" href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/" title="Постельное бельё" alt="Постельное бельё">Постельное бельё <sup>68</sup></a><ul class="main_menu" style="padding-left:12px;" id="category_128"><li><img current="1" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/btn-expand.png" class="category_button" style="cursor:pointer; padding-right:2px;" id="image-136"><a class="category_button" id="button-136" href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/" title="по плотности ткани" alt="по плотности ткани">по плотности ткани <sup>68</sup></a><ul style="display:none;padding-left:12px;" "="" id="category_136"><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/kpb_po_plotnost_105/" title="105 гр/м" alt="105 гр/м">105 гр/м <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/kpb_po_plotnost_110/" title="110 гр/м" alt="110 гр/м">110 гр/м <sup>0</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/kpb_po_plotnost_115/" title="115 гр/м" alt="115 гр/м">115 гр/м <sup>6</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/kbp_po_plotn_120/" title="120 гр/м" alt="120 гр/м">120 гр/м <sup>4</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/kpb_plotn_125/" title="125 гр/м" alt="125 гр/м">125 гр/м <sup>27</sup></a></li><li style="padding-left:12px"><a href="http://training/dom_textile/postel_belio/kpb_po_plotn/kpb_po_plotnost_130/" title="130
```

...and more

Comment: for example if I click on some category, the img source also changes for +(closed) and -(opened)...

Comment: I just need a little advice on how to implement it into my code, or if you will, a little piece of code)

Comment: By now i don't use the variable $change - its just for you to see, because i don't know how to make it, so plaese help

Answer (score 0):

Try to save DOM id of menu opened to cookie, and after refresh page, check your cookie, then get last saved menu's DOM id and use jquery to simulate click by call

```
$('#id').click();
```